# Can i use if/else to change the style on my li elements

Tags: php

```
<?php if($notification['user_status']==0){?>
    <li  style="background-color: #edf2fa;">
<?php } else { ?>
    <li  style="background-color: white;">
<?php } ?>
    <a id="notification_list" href="index.php?page=<?php echo $page?>&act=notification">
    <?php echo $notefor; ?><small style="color:#AAA; padding-left:10px;">
    <?php echo $time_frame;?></small>
    </a></li>
```

The first if statement will run fine but the else will not run, is there a way to do something similar.

Comment: Not sure what exactly your question is? This code looks syntaxically correct and will output different `<li>` opening tags depending on the condition.

Comment: What does `$notification['user_status'])` contain? What kind of values did it have that you expected not to match the if condition?

Comment: @Don'tPanic it was a integer it will have an initial value of 0 when clicked on it's value will be changed to 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure,
But try to put the color in a separate variable, and do the PHP logic first, and then use the variable once, instead of rewriting the whole `li`:

example:

```
<?php 
$color = 'white';
if($notification['user_status']==0){
$color = '#edf2fa';
}
?>
<li  style="background-color: <?php echo $color; ?>;">
```

Comment: I have a foreach loop that will loop through every row to show the notification. By default it will show the color #edf2fa since the _value of the user_status is 0_ on all my notification, as soon as i click on one of them the user_status for that notification is changed to 1,_all other notification has user_status of 0_ but all my notification is changed to white. I have tried putting the $color outside the for each. change the value of the conditions.

Comment: in that case, you would just need to append `else{ $color = 'white'; }` to the end of the `if` above. This happens because the variable has already inherited a value `white` from the previous foreach loop. Adding the `else` statement will ensure that in each loop it will check and properly set the value every time. Again, it really depends on the whole picture of what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are running php 5.4 >

First of all this code could use some cleanup.

```
<?php

if ( $notification['user_status'] == 0 ) {
    $backgroundColor = '#edf2fa';
}else {
    $backgroundColor = '#FFFFFF';
}

?>

<li  style="background-color: <?= $backgroundColor ?>;">
    <a id="notification_list" href="index.php?page=<?= $page ?>&act=notification">
        <?= $notefor; ?>
        <small style="color:#AAA; padding-left:10px;"><?= $time_frame;?></small>
    </a>
</li>
```

The else codeblock will only run if the result of the expresssion inside the if statement equates to false. so if you would kindly check if `$notification['user_status']` actually is unequal to `0` in the case you expect the else code to run.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the if statement inside something like the following:

```
<li style="background-color: <?php ($notification['user_status'] == 0) ? print '#edf2fa' : print 'white' ?>">
  <a id="notification_list" href="index.php?page=<?php echo $page ?>&act=notification">
    <?php echo $notefor; ?>
    <small style="color:#AAA; padding-left:10px;">
      <?php echo $time_frame; ?></small>
  </a>
</li>
```